# Graphs - Proof that when all vertices of G have degree <=2, then each component of G is a path or a cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

I am absolutely new to graph theory, so sorry if it seems way basic.

I have been trying to prove it by contradiction, saying that G has a component C that is not a path or a cycle.

In that case, the only possibility is C being a tree? If that's the case, how do I prove that a tree that is not also a path has a vertice with degree >3?

Comment: I think you mean to say "all vertices have degree $\le 2$"

Comment: No, the component doesn't have to be a tree.  What about a cycle with a path coming out of it?  Anyway, the statement isn't true.  What about $K_4?$  Each vertex has degree $3$ and $K_4$ is neither a path nor a cycle.  Are you sure you've got the question right?

Comment: Sorry guys, it's actually all degrees with <=2. My bad

Answer (score 1):

First, it's enough to prove that if $G$ is connected and the maximum degree of $G$ is $\le 2$ then $G$ is a path or a cycle. (Or $G$ consists of a single vertex.)  First suppose that every vertex is of degree $2$.  Then the graph has an Euler circuit.  Complete the proof in this case by arguing that the circuit must be a cycle.

Otherwise, consider a path of maximal length in $G$.  Say the end vertices are $x$ and $y$.  Each of $x$ and $y$ is of degree one, or we could build a longer path.  If the path from $x$ to $y$ is all of $G$ we are done, so suppose there is some vertex $z$ not on the path, and deduce a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "path of maximal length?"

Comment: The length of a path is the number of edges in it. I'm talking about a simple path, where no edge vertex is visited twice.  There are only finitely paths, obviously, so there is one of length as great as any other.